# Where in Django Charfield() is max_length defined as compulsory?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

I have a Django app and trying to understand the logic on how to read docs correctly in order to e.g. create a Charfield object.

So here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField()
    . . . . . .
```

If I run the app I get the error:

`Charfields must define a 'max_length' attribute`

I get that I need to do:

`f_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)`

But why? when I read the code for Charfield it's not there, so I read the code for its superclass Field but I don't see where max_length is set to be compulsory!

Please assist (new to oop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the check is [right here in the definition of `CharField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa9ac16c1345a7fb6ad500c84961a954529ba2b9/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1133-L1155), as a Django system check (`def _check_max_length_attribute(self, **kwargs):`):

```
def _check_max_length_attribute(self, **kwargs):
    if self.max_length is None:
        return [
            checks.Error("CharFields must define a 'max_length' attribute.",
                obj=self,
                id="fields.E120",
            )
        ]
    # ...
```

It's hooked up to be a [Django system check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/checks/) for `CharFields` in the  `check` function just above.

For future reference, I found it by just searching for `CharFields must define a` in the Django code base.